# Treatment of mathematical logic with less bookkeeping?

Tags: logic, soft-question, first-order-logic, model-theory

My only real experience with mathematical logic is an undergrad-level model theory class that I took some years ago. My (perhaps fair, perhaps unfair) take away from this class was that mathematical logic as it is usually presented involves a lot of *bookkeeping*: keeping track of enumeration of variables, arity of function and relation symbols, etc. My impression was *also* that this bookkeeping was in some sense superfluous. Though the potential for off-by-one errors in writing down some statement abound, nothing of great consequence ever really hinges on the arities or variable-enumerations involved (edit: except perhaps broad cardinality distinctions, finite/countably infinite/uncountable). Perhaps I am wrong about this—if so, I would greatly like to see an example of where these things really are pivotal. But my impression, again not so informed, is that a lot of this bookkeeping is simply a product of the language we use to talk about logic, which seems not to have changed much since the early twentieth centuries and which predates a lot of modern mathematical formalism.

It would seem to me that modern language, e.g. from category theory, has the potential to clarify the presentation a lot. For example, we might think of the set of terms and formulas in a given signature as being the object in a certain category freely generated by the variable symbols and the function- and relation-symbols viewed as partial functions. Indeed I think something like this is the view taken up in universal algebra. And while some might (fairly) view this as overcomplicating things, to my eye it is perhaps a less messy presentation than the traditional one in terms of literal strings of symbols. For instance, it makes it immediately obvious that one can make definitions recursively on terms and/or formulas.

This example is I suppose a bit trivial, but I'm not really wedded to this particular concern or this particular rewording of things. My more general question is just whether there is any text on any aspect of mathematical logic that attempts to cut away some of the bookkeeping by reframing things in more modern language, and if there is, if anyone could point me to it. Thanks!

Comment: TBH, this post seems like a bunch of word salad. The way you describe bookeeping applies to pretty much any science or math field, doesn't it?

Comment: A study of logic will necessarily study some aspect of syntax, and that will again necessarily carry some tedious bookkeeping. However this can be mitigated by bundling it up nicely, one such approach is categorical as you suggested. Check for example Jacob's Categorical Logic. It does not study first order logic, however, but introduces some mechanisms to hide the bookkeeping. For example, a signature can be seen as a certain pullback.

I'd also be very interested to see a heavily categorical study of FOL.

Comment: @Accelerator: Of somewhat related interest (see the comments about "hair"): [Is computability theory less cumulative than other areas in mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/432405/15780)

Comment: How on earth can be *superfluous* to "keep track of the arity of function and relation symbols, etc."? Type-checking of this kind is utterly fundamental to avoid garbage.

Comment: For what it is worth, in the rules of inference implemented in my math-oriented proof checker, the function $f$ can have different arities. The unary $f$ is treated as if it was another function altogether from a binary version.  You can even have $f(x)=f(x,y)$. The arity is determined by the context. It hasn't caused any problems. Likewise for predicates.

Comment: Arities show up in universal algebra too.

Answer (score 0):

> My impression was also that this bookkeeping was in some sense
> superfluous.

Maybe. This is *not* the definitive answer, just some food for thought...

Define $(f,X,Y)$ as :

1. $\forall a:[ a\in X\to f(a)\in Y]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~($Equivalently $f:X\to
       Y~)$

Why can we not then also  define $(f,X^2,Y)$ as:

2. $\forall a,b:[(a,b) \in X^2 \to f(a,b) \in Y]~~~~~~($Equivalently $f:
       X^2\to~Y)$

It might be a little confusing, but it would save on what the you call "bookkeeping." I don't think it would it lead to any internal contradictions.

$f(x)$ would obviously be defined by (1). And $f(x,y)$ would be defined by (2).

We could even make sense of $f(x)=f(x,y)$

Technically, changing the name of the binary version in (2) would make no logical difference AFAICT.